# Configuration issue with Mule ftpExt transport

Tags: ftp, esb, file-transfer, mule

I am using mule esb to transfer file from ftp to local directory. I am not using the standard FTP connector but the [extended one](http://code.google.com/p/mule-ftpext/).

I am getting an error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://localhost/schemaftpext/mule-ftpext.xsd'.
```

Actually I am new to Mule ESB, so i do not what is the url "http://localhost/schemaftpext/mule-ftpext.xsd" says that. I need to put anything in localhost?

FYI: I am using the example "http://code.google.com/p/mule-ftpext/source/browse/trunk/Test/mule-config.xml?spec=svn23&r=23". What should i do for that localhost URL?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the standard FTP transport but FtpExt instead?

Comment: I do not any idea about this. I was looking on the Google for ftp file transfer using mule and tried to execute samples. I have to look on the difference between those things.

Comment: Then use the official FTP transport for Mule, which comes bundled with Mule. Doc here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/FTP+Transport+Reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://localhost/schemaftpext/mule-ftpext.xsd is just a schema URI location: there is no need to have anything available there, it is just used as an identifier. Mule's configuration loader will resolve this URI to an actual location at load-up time. The actual location is within ftpExt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Now this implies that you need to have is the ftpExt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar available in Mule's classpath. Is that the case?

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks for the support.And my config xml has below  <flow name="HTTP input1"> <ftp:inbound-endpoint user="username" password="secret" 
                host="host" path="location" port="21"> <file:filename-wildcard-filter 
                pattern="*.*" />
                 </ftp:inbound-endpoint> <file:outbound-endpoint 
                path="E:/Mule/Inbound" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]"
                > 
                </file:outbound-endpoint> </flow>

Comment: and its moving the file from ftp to that location. Could you tell me that how can i read the file content and based on that i need to put the file to corresponding folder?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Since it seems it's another question, please open a new question. Comments are not appropriate for that.

Comment: Okay Sure. I have created new one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292038/mule-esb-file-content-read. Please post your answer there. Thanks