# Content based file moving with Mule

Tags: file, ftp, esb, mule

My mule config file contains the below flow:

```
<flow name="HTTP input1">
  <ftp:inbound-endpoint user="username" password="secret" host="host" path="location" port="21">
    <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="." />
  </ftp:inbound-endpoint>
  <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:/Mule/Inbound" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" >
  </file:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

I'm able to move the files but what I need is to read out the file content and based on that content place it in specific directory.

For example if my file content has "Vendor1" then it should place the file under Vendor1. FYI: Vendor1 is not static. It may Vendor1000. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

- Extract the desired value from the file using a transformer (not an expression because none support your specific file format),
- Use this property in the path attribute of the outbound endpoint.

Something like:

```
<flow name="HTTP input1">
  <ftp:inbound-endpoint user="username"
                        password="secret"
                        host="host"
                        path="location"
                        port="21">
    <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="." />
  </ftp:inbound-endpoint>
  <script:transformer name="stringReplaceWithParams">
    <script:script engine="groovy">
        <script:text>
          // here the payload variable should contain a byte[] from the remote FTP file
          // ... munch-munch the byte[] with Groovy to find the value to put in targetSubDir
          var targetSubDir = ...

          message.setOuboundProperty('targetSubDir', targetSubDir) 
          // return the payload unchanged, we just changed a message property
          return payload 
        </script:text>
    </script:script>
  </script:transformer>
  <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:/Mule/Inbound/#[header:targetSubDir]"
                          outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Really Thanks for your support.Also I got your point but i have a doubt that is how can i read the file using mule expressions? or if i write custom class, then how can i assign the return value to the property key? May be its a simple question to you but i could not get it .

Comment: The non-streaming inbound FTP endpoint reads the remote file as a byte[]. You can then use a Mule expression to fetch a value from this byte[]. For example, if the remote file is in XML format, you can use an XPath expression to extract the desired value. If you specify the format of this file, I'll improve my answer.

Comment: OK, how do you find the desired value in this CSV file?

Comment: By using comma separator.is it possible here?

Comment: Everything's possible :) I'm trying to have you giving me more details so I can update my answer. But with what you've provided so far, I can't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5413/discussion-between-david-dossot-and-palani)

Comment: The method  message.setOuboundProperty() is expecting String,Object parameters.So passing string value is not accepted. How the property will create folder name? is any conversion i need to do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "passing string value is not accepted"? What parameters are you passing to setOuboundProperty?

Comment: I passed a String value to that. It is not accepted as its expects Object.

Comment: I passed something like this "message.setOuboundProperty('targetSubDir', 'targetSubDir') " for testing

Comment: Share your full config and full stack on pastebin. Join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5413/discussion-between-david-dossot-and-palani

Comment: I have used the your solution and got succeeded. I made a small change that is i have added message.setProperty('targetSubDir', targetSubDir) instead of message.setOuboundProperty('targetSubDir', targetSubDir).Thanks

Comment: message.setProperty is deprecated - http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) Avoid using it! It has the same signature as setOuboundProperty, so setOuboundProperty should work!

Comment: Okay,I understood. Now i changed it to setOuboundProperty and working fine. But Last time i got an error while using this. Will post the same if i fall on any issue. Thanks